# multiple bullets pygame space invaders

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to make a little space invaders game. My problem is that I can not have more then one bullet on the screen. I'd like to be able to fire at least 3 like in the original game. What would be the best way to do so ?

Here is my code:

```
from pygame import *
import random

class Sprite:

        def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
                self.x = xpos
                self.y = ypos
                self.bitmap = image.load(filename)
                self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        def set_position(self, xpos, ypos):
                self.x = xpos
                self.y = ypos
        def render(self):
                screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x, self.y))

def Intersect(s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y):
        if (s1_x > s2_x - 30) and (s1_x < s2_x + 30) and (s1_y > s2_y - 30) and (s1_y < s2_y + 30):
                return 1
        else:
                return 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode((640,480))
key.set_repeat(1, 1)
display.set_caption('PyInvaders')
backdrop = image.load('data/backdrop.bmp') 
enemies = []

x = 0
count = 0

for count in range(10):
    if count < 10:
        enemies.append(Sprite(50 * x + 50, 50, 'data/baddie.bmp'))
        x += 1
        count += 1
    else:
        x = 0
        enemies.append(Sprite(100 * x + 100, 50, 'data/baddie.bmp'))
        x += 1





hero = Sprite(20, 400, 'data/hero.bmp')
ourmissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'data/heromissile.bmp')
enemymissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'data/baddiemissile.bmp')
gameover = image.load('data/gameover.bmp')



quit = 0
enemyspeed = 4
timer = 0        


while quit == 0:

        heromid = hero.x + 16
        screen.blit(backdrop, (0, 0))

        for count in range(len(enemies)):
                enemies[count].x += enemyspeed
                enemies[count].render()

        if enemies[len(enemies)-1].x > 590:
                enemyspeed = -3
                for count in range(len(enemies)):
                        enemies[count].y += 5

        if enemies[0].x < 10:
                enemyspeed = 3
                for count in range(len(enemies)):
                        enemies[count].y += 5

        if ourmissile.y < 640 and ourmissile.y > 0:
            ourmissile.render()
            ourmissile.y += -5
            timer  = timer + 1

        if enemymissile.y >= 480 and len(enemies) > 0:
            enemymissile.x = enemies[random.randint(0, len(enemies) - 1)].x + 16
            enemymissile.y = enemies[0].y

        if Intersect(hero.x, hero.y, enemymissile.x, enemymissile.y):
           quit = 1

        for count in range(0, len(enemies)):
            if Intersect(ourmissile.x, ourmissile.y, enemies[count].x, enemies[count].y):
                    del enemies[count]
                    break

        if len(enemies) == 0:
            quit = 1

        for ourevent in event.get():
                if ourevent.type == QUIT:
                        quit = 1
                if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if ourevent.key == K_RIGHT and hero.x < 590:
                                hero.x += 5
                        if ourevent.key == K_LEFT and hero.x > 10:
                                hero.x -= 5
                        if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
                            if timer < 400:
                                timer = 0
                                ourmissile.x = heromid
                                ourmissile.y = hero.y

        enemymissile.render()
        enemymissile.y += 5

        hero.render()

        display.update()
        time.delay(10)


while quit == 1:
    screen.blit(gameover,(0,0))
    display.update()
    if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
        if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
            quit == 0
```

Comment: With your current code. Thats not going to be easy, but I would recommend looking into classes and data arrays, etc. Create a class for your bullets. Create a class for the enemies bullets. Take a look at this site for a bit of inspiration: http://pygame.org/tags/spaceinvaders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having one missile, make a missile list. So instead of this:

```
if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
    if timer < 400:
        timer = 0
        ourmissile.x = heromid
        ourmissile.y = hero.y
```

Create a new missile and add it to the list:

```
if timer < 400:
    timer = 0
    missiles.append(Sprite(heromid, hero.y, 'data/heromissile.bmp')
```

Add loops to draw and move all the missiles:

```
for m in missiles:
    if m.y < 640 and m.y > 0:
        m.render()
        m.y += -5
```

Comment: hey i tried this and it worked thanks, but i now get one continuous bullet i'd like to delay it so wait 50 miliseconds between each bullet to prevent the user to just stay pressed on space bar and have one continuous bullet

Comment: @user3454855 make a timer, check if enough seconds have passed when pressing space

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's be frank. You're gonna have to recode most of that. Here is an example of how I did it:

I created a sprite group (It holds multiple sprites)

```
bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Then I made a class for the bullets

```
# The pygame.sprite.Sprite is necessary
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    # What this line means is that whenever a bullet is created it goes in the group "bulletGroup"
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, bulletGroup)
```

And now to create a bullet:

```
# You can execute this same line as many times as you want and the bullets will be seperate
bullet = Bullet(x, y)
```

If you need help on moving them in this format let me know, hope it helps!

And not to sound mean but I'm really trynna get reputation atm :)